# How to handle duplicate elements in array while finding pivot point through divide and conquer approach

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

I have been given a sorted and rotated array and I need to find the pivot index for this array.And for this I made a function findPivot.
But the problem is that it cannot handle the duplicate elements in array.
for example in {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2} and {2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}. It doesn’t look possible to decide whether to recur for left half or right half by doing constant number of comparisons at the middle.
So how to handle it for duplicates in O(log n) time complexity?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int findPivot(int arr[],int low,int high);  
int pivotedBinarySearch(int arr[],int n, int key);
int binarySearch(int arr[],int low,int high,int key);
int main()
{
int arr1[10]={2,2,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
int key = 0;
int size = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
printf("the number is found at index %d\n",pivotedBinarySearch(arr1,size,key));
return 0;

}
int pivotedBinarySearch(int arr[],int n,int key)
{
int p = findPivot(arr,0,n-1);
if(arr[p]==key)
    return p;
if(key>=arr[0])
    return binarySearch(arr,0,p-1,key);
return binarySearch(arr,p+1,n-1,key);

}
int binarySearch(int arr[],int low,int high,int key)
{
if(low > high)
    return -1;
int mid = (low + high)/2;
if(arr[mid]==key)
    return mid;
if(key>arr[mid])
    return binarySearch(arr,mid+1,high,key);
return binarySearch(arr,low,mid-1,key);
}
int findPivot(int arr[],int low,int high)
{
if(high == low)
    return low;
int mid = high+low/2;
if(arr[mid]>arr[mid+1])
    return mid;
if(arr[mid-1]>arr[mid])
    return mid-1;
if(arr[low]>=arr[mid])
    return findPivot(arr,low,mid-1);
return findPivot(arr,mid+1,high);       
}
```

Comment: There are bugs. One that leaps out is "int mid = high+low/2;"  Post a minimal, complete program that shows the faulty behavior, along with a description of the desired behavior.

Comment: No I don't think there is any bug in this part except this program is restricted only for array with no similar elements. This operation has O(log n) time complexity. And I am just asking that how can I find the pivot index for the array with similar elements with same time complexity.(Note -: Pivot index for a sorted and rotated array is the index of maximum value element e.g. in {11,12,13,6,7,8,9}  2 is the pivot index )

Comment: It should be mid = (high+low)/2;  Operator precedance. Post a minimal, complete program if you want someone to debug it.

Comment: When all are same except 1 does O(logn) even exist? Wont you have to check both left and right arrays for the 'pivot'?

Comment: @JiveDadson I wouldn't recommend using the mid = (low+high)/2 approach. Leads to loads of integer overflow exceptions, particularly when arrays are large. It is rather better to use mid = low + (high-low)/2

Comment: @venividivinci I thought that might be confusing.  The bug has to do with operator precedence, not overflow.

Comment: @VeniVidiVinci Sorry but I am not able to understand why did you use mid = low + (high - low)/2  instead of mid = (low+high)/2 as both of them leads to the same result?

Comment: Google is your friend! Read more about it on: https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: @VeniVidiVinci That's great, thanks for the article now it's clear to me.